# JS: How to filter object property and became key

Tags: javascript, object

I have a object like this

```
"field": {
      "zh":{ 
          "game_code" : "游戏", 
          "transfer_amount" : "金额", 
          "uni_id" : "流水号", 
          "create_time" : "建立时间"
      },
      "en": { 
          "game_code" : "GameCode", 
          "transfer_amount" : "Amount", 
          "uni_id" : "UniqId.", 
          "create_time" : "CreateTime"
      }
    }
}
```

and I want to format data like this

```
data: [
  {
    game_code: {
      zh: '游戏',
      en: 'GameCode'
    },
  },
  {
    transfer_amount: {
      zh: '金额',
      en: 'Amount'
    }
  }
]
```

what is the best way to do this ? thanks
(I edited that I wanna format data code)

Comment: Have you made any attempts yourself yet? If so, what have you tried and what did / did not work?

Comment: The best way would be to write this simple code on your own

Comment: Your example result isn't valid JS. Arrays do not have named properties

Comment: thanks a lot. I already edit the example code. array not name properties. thanks for your notice that mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, get all keys for your result data, and then loop through `data.betlog_field` for language key? Here is the code:

```js
const data: any = {
  "betlog_field": {
    "zh": {
      "game_code": "游戏",
      "transfer_amount": "金额",
      "uni_id": "流水号",
      "create_time": "建立时间"
    },
    "en": {
      "game_code": "GameCode",
      "transfer_amount": "Amount",
      "uni_id": "UniqId.",
      "create_time": "CreateTime"
    }
  }
};

let result: any = { data: [] };
console.clear();
let keys = Object.keys(data.betlog_field.zh);
keys.forEach(key => {
  let item: any = {};
  Object.keys(data.betlog_field).forEach((lan: any) => {
    item[lan] = data.betlog_field[lan][key];
  });

  result.data.push({[key]: item});
});

console.log(result);
```